# Show that the curve is contained in a plane.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, 3d

> If all osculating planes of a regular curve pass through one point, show that the curve is contained in a plane.

---

> The osculating plane equation is as follows:
> $$\begin{vmatrix}
> X-x & Y-y & Z-z \\ 
> x' & y' & z' \\
> x'' & y'' & z''
> \end{vmatrix}=0$$
> or $(R-r, r', r'') = 0$ where $R = (X,Y,Z)$ and $r = r(t)$ is the curve equation.

The first idea came to my mind was showing that the torsion is zero everywhere, but I do not see how to observe this fact.

Let $M(A,B,C)$ be the point that all those planes pass through. Then, for any value of $t$, we have
$$\begin{vmatrix}
A-x & B-y & C-z \\ 
x' & y' & z' \\
x'' & y'' & z''
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
Expanding the determinant does not seem to give anything. I got stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply Serret-Frenet.

WLOG the common point is the origin and the curve is parametrised by arclength $s$.  The given condition says $\mathbf{r}\cdot(\mathbf{r}'\times\mathbf{r}'')=0$.

Since $\mathbf{r}'\times\mathbf{r}''=\mathbf{T}\times\mathbf{T}'=\kappa\mathbf{T}\times\mathbf{N}=\kappa\mathbf{B}$, either we have $\kappa=0$ on an interval (so we are done), or $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$ on an interval.

Differentiating $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$ gives $\mathbf{r}\cdot\tau\mathbf{N}=0$ so again either zero torsion on an interval (so we are done) or $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{N}=0$ on an interval.  Since $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$ we have $\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{T})\mathbf{T}$ so $\kappa=0$.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! However, I cannot get the last sentence: "Since $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$ we have $\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{T})\mathbf{T}$ so $\kappa=0$".

Comment: Since $\mathbf{T},\mathbf{N},\mathbf{B}$ forms an orthonormal basis, we have $\mathbf{r}$ must be in the $\mathbf{T}$ direction.  But that means when you differentiate $\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{T})\mathbf{T}$ the $\mathbf{N}$-component is $\kappa(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{T})=0$.